# Accessing a remote service in Java through it's web interface using JAX-WS for SOAP

Tags: java, python, soap, jax-ws

I have a public EJB class that I want accessible online as a web service.  I have generated a WSDL and the SOAP mesasging seems to work. I used soapUI to test the connection. What I'm not clear about is how would I then use this exposed web service. I'd like to try another language like Python to then make calls through that interface. I know that the WSDL is supposed to help a potential client build it's client side code but I'm not sure about how to specify the connection and location and login information if I had that. I know I'm asking a large topic but any information would help. Thanks

Edit: so basicaly I'm just wondering do I have to use tools to generate my client code from the WSDL like axis2. Or whatever Python uses. Or can I write the code by hand? What's generally done. is the server reference included in that WSDL and are call methods generated usually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ZSI](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/zsi.html)

But ZSI is too complex and spends more time to generate proxies

I suggest you to use [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/). suds generates the proxies On the fly and so fast, i used it in some projects.

another packages are available:

1. [soaplib](http://soaplib.github.com/soaplib/2_0/)
2. [SOAPy](http://soapy.sourceforge.net/)
3. [pysimplesoap](http://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/)

Comment: Thanks I'm looking at suds now.